# How to copy a clip image on the canvas

Tags: html, html5-canvas

The code below works fine but how can I make a copy of my "StopLicht" and place a copy elsewhere on the canvas?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p>Image to use:</p>
<img id="sprite-sheet" src="logi.bmp" alt="Logi" width="220" height="277">
<p>Canvas:</p>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="512" height="380" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
<script>
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var img = document.getElementById("sprite-sheet"); 
    function StopLicht() {
//rij x groen stoplicht
ctx.drawImage(img, 64, 8,8,8,80, 0,8,8);
ctx.drawImage(img, 72, 8,8,8,88, 0,8,8);
ctx.drawImage(img, 80, 8,8,8,80, 8,8,8);
ctx.drawImage(img, 88, 8,8,8,88, 8,8,8);
ctx.drawImage(img,112,24,8,8,80,16,8,8);
ctx.drawImage(img,120,24,8,8,88,16,8,8);   
ctx.drawImage(img, 96, 8,8,8,80,24,8,8);
ctx.drawImage(img,104, 8,8,8,88,24,8,8);
}
StopLicht();   //geef het stoplicht weer. en is goed !
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, you can use canvas translate to reposition your stoplight to any x,y position on the canvas:**

context.translate(x,y) will move the canvas origin(0,0) to x,y.

This means you can your existing drawImage commands without altering each of their x,y positions.

```
function StopLicht(x,y) {

    //save the untransformed context state
    ctx.save();

    // move the canvas to the desired xy coordinate
    ctx.translate(x,y);

    //rij x groen stoplicht
    ctx.drawImage(img, 64, 8,8,8,80, 0,8,8);
    ctx.drawImage(img, 72, 8,8,8,88, 0,8,8);
    ctx.drawImage(img, 80, 8,8,8,80, 8,8,8);
    ctx.drawImage(img, 88, 8,8,8,88, 8,8,8);
    ctx.drawImage(img,112,24,8,8,80,16,8,8);
    ctx.drawImage(img,120,24,8,8,88,16,8,8);   
    ctx.drawImage(img, 96, 8,8,8,80,24,8,8);
    ctx.drawImage(img,104, 8,8,8,88,24,8,8);

    // restore the context to its untransformed state
    ctx.restore();

}
```

**[ addition: example usage ]**

This loop will print 2 rows of 10 lights:

```
for(var row=0;row<2;row++){
for(var col=0;col<10;col++){
    StopLicht(row*12,col*12);
}}
```

Comment: Hi Mark,Thanks for the answer. But it not what I expect. It is good to know "Translate" to relocate. What I need is two "StopLicht" on my canvas. The original and a copy somewere. It is one of the background parts. So I need FG: 10 "StopLicht" on a row and fg 2 lines. Erik

Comment: You can call StopLicht multiple times to draw multiple lights.  See the addition to my answer.  Good luck with your project!